# RuntimeException when I create a new Symfony Project

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

good afternoon. I'm having trouble creating a new symfony project.
When I enter the following command in the terminal:

```
symfony new mufasa
```

The terminal return to me the next message:

> [RuntimeException]
>     The selected version (3.3.12) cannot be installed because it does not exist
>     .
>     Execute the following command to install the latest stable Symfony release:
>     /usr/local/bin/symfony new mufasa

I have tried to update the symfony application using `symfony self-update` but is up to date:

> // Symfony Installer is already updated to the latest version (1.5.9).

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this please:

```
symfony new mufasa 3.3.11
```

release 3.3.12 was released some hours ago:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/releases

But there is a similar issue:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony-installer/issues/141

Comment: glad to help you!, when you can accept the answer to help other guys with your same problem in the future! @Sermanes